# Mysql creating lot of table or less tables, which is better?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently working on a webapp that is heavily depend upon lot of data from database. Consider the following case.

**A) Table design with Predefined tables only**

```
1)table vehicle_type
------------------
id|name
------------------
1 |car
2 |truck
3 |bike
-------------------
2)table users
-------------------
id|name
-------------------
1 |James
2 |John
3 |Stefen
-------------------
3)table ownership
--------------------------------
id|vehicle_type_id|user_id|count
--------------------------------
1 | 1             |1      |30
2 | 1             |3      |20
3 | 3             |2      |13
--------------------------------
```

**B) Table design with dynamically creating tables using app logic, that is when a new entry comes in vehicle_type we create a new table with that name**

```
1)table vehicle_type
------------------
id|name
------------------
1 |car
2 |truck
3 |bike
-------------------
2)table users
-------------------
id|name
-------------------
1 |James
2 |John
-------------------
3)dynamic_table car
-------------------
id|user_id|count
-------------------
1 |1      |20
2 |2      |10
-------------------
3)dynamic_table truck
-------------------
id|user_id|count
-------------------
1 |3      |15
2 |2      |20
3 |1      |12
-------------------
4)dynamic_table bike
-------------------
id|user_id|count
-------------------
1 |1      |4
2 |2      |12
-------------------
```

In second case table vehicle_type act as key to dynamic tables. In first I used ownership the table to store the data of count of vehicle type that each owner has, in second I create dynamic tables for each vehicle type and stores each vehicle type count in seperate table.I think this approach will make the scaling of database relatively easy and querying much efficient,than using a single table ownership.

I have never worked with large set of data but this one will have lot of data for sure. 
Please note above tables are used as sampels not part of real application logic.

Please suggest the merits and demerits of each method.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is a "dynamic" table?

Comment: IMHO, dynamic tables are not a good idea for any type of persistent data.  They have a use for transient data for which you do not care about the long-term viability.  In your case, I would define "large set of data".  Mysql handles millions of rows just fine on this type of data with proper indexing.

Comment: @ypercube I am just referring tables created using application logic during when we need them.

Comment: @DavidFleeman Thanks for the suggestion but can you tell me why is is not a good practice ? I had used a pincode database that had pincode to geo location data for the entire world in one database, which was took so much time to do select query, when I tried to partition table by country it was faster than previous one table approach. like I said i dont have much experience with database optimisation :)

Comment: @RohithRaveendran Did you use indexes for your big table in geo location project?

Comment: Yes used indexing for the table primary key as well as pincode(which I am not sure I did or not)

Comment: I agree with @DavidFleeman comment, but if for some reason you still want to go with one table for each vehicle type.. why don't you create all the tables in advance? How much vehicle types can exist?!

Comment: Actually I was trying to refer this world city database 
id|city|city_accent|region|population|latitude|longitude 
Which had total of 3,156,054 records but select query was painfully slow in my system

Comment: @RohithRaveendran - I just fail to believe that performance is so impacted by amount of data that the overhead of managing multiple dynamic tables outweighs using a properly indexed table.  Could you tell us how many rows of data so we can get a better perspective?  With your current schema, a good table index would give very good performance with MILLIONS of rows.

Comment: @Babblo Sorry I was just using a example, actual tables are not related with this example, in my actual scenario data comes instead of vehicle_type can be infinite as it being added by user. Each user can add any number of data.

Comment: @DavidFleeman consider a situation where vehicle_type table is replaced with world_artists and ownership table is submission_count_by_user

A user add a new author if he doesn't exist in database while submitting a new article/post/poem etc. So we add that new author to world_authers table and create a entry  for submission_count_by_user with data id of the author id of user and total number of submissions by user for that particular author. 

(Sorry if my example is really bad :( )

Comment: @Rohith Raveendran in that case ("infinite" variations) I definitely wouldn't recommend using separate tables. If you think the amount of records will be really big, maybe you can apply some partitioning.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

Comment: @DavidFleeman So why do mysql suggest using table partitions for better performance ? i dont have better much idea about it 

Partitioning enables tables and indexes or index-organized tables to be subdivided into smaller manageable pieces and these each small piece is called a "partition".

So may be second approach in example can be considered as logical partition of table ??

Comment: @Rohith Raveendran look at my previous comment, these are the droids your are looking for :)

Comment: @RohithRaveendran I generally agree with your point. Both partitioning single table and manually splitting the data into tables might work. The question is which one suits you better :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what a dynamic table is. There is no single correct answer for question "which is better". So it depends on the project. Here are some possible opinions.

**First approach (one table):**

Pros:

- Less code/time/effort to start ;
- Easier to maintain (might not be the case) ;
- Queries can go over the whole data set ;
- As the data set grows, you might apply [table partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html) to handle performance issues ;

Cons:

- Data set will grow faster ;
- Less agile (e.g there are some additional ownership properties for a specific vehicle type ) ;

**Second approach: multiple tables**

Pros:

- Might be more agile ;
- Might scale a bit better ;

Cons:

- More code/time/effort to start ;
- Harder to maintain (might be false);

As a general advice: consider your data access patterns. It should help you to understand.

- What queries are you going to use?
- Which of them are going to be executed more often?
- Are there going to be more read or write operations?
- What is you data going to be distributed ?